# Is it fair that error parameters are included in calculation of Occam factor? Why?

Tags: bayesian, model-comparison

Suppose I am comparing models $M1$, $M2$ of the form

$M_i: y = f_i(\beta_i,x) + \epsilon_i$

where

$\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i)$

in other words the deterministic part of the models $f_i$ varies, but the error model for each is the same albeit with different variance. The parameters of each model can be seen as the parameters for the deterministic part $\beta_i$ plus the error parameters for each model $\sigma_i$.

Suppose I now compute the evidence integral of each to compare the models. [Mackay page 349](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/itprnn/ps/343.355.pdf) demonstrates that part of the evidence integral can be interpreted as the Occam factor which will penalize not only models which have more parameters, but also models in which parameters have to be finely tuned to obtain a good likelihood.

This seems entirely fair, except in respect of the error parameter $\sigma_i$. Surely the extent to which you can quantify the error distribution should have no bearing on the model quality? Won't a model with very small $\sigma$, i.e. a better model, thus be penalized more by Occam (even though this should be outweighed by higher likelihoods)?

Obviously with more complex error models it would be possible to 'cheat' a model comparison by hiding more parameters $\beta'_i$ inside the error model e.g.

$\epsilon_i \sim N(g_i(\beta'_i,x),\sigma_i)$

and while it's questionable whether you could call that an error model at all, more subtle mistakes or intellectual dishonesty of this form might involve heteroskedastic and skewed error distributions.

Returning to the first error model though, should $\sigma_i$ be discounted from model comparison, and if so how? Or if not, why not?